# Not been able to dismiss keyboard on tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I am trying to dismiss keyboard on tap anywhere in the view. Here is my code

```
- (void)registerForNotifcationOfKeyboard
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    CGRect bkgndRect = activeField.superview.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
    [activeField.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0,kbSize.height/2 - activeField.frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
}

- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;
}

-(BOOL) disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
{
    return NO;
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self registerForNotifcationOfKeyboard];
     self.progressBar.hidden = YES;

    UIGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) dismissKeyboard
{
    [activeField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

when I press tap anywhere this function `dismissKeyboard` does get called but it never dismiss the keyboard.

Kindly If anyone has any idea

Best Regards

Comment: did you connected delegate to file owner in xib file properly ?or else you can use activeField.delegate=self; in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **always** works for me:

```
//if `dismissKeyboard` is located in your `UIViewController`'s sublass: 
-(void) dismissKeyboard
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

From UIView Class Reference:

```
 This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder.   
If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force parameter is set to **YES**, the text field is never even asked; it is **forced to resign**.
```

Answer (score 1):

I complelety agree with @Lukasz :  Use  view's endEditing property to dissmiss keyboard

```
-(void) dismissKeyboard
{
  [self.view endEditing:YES]; //this will dissmiss keyboard;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

before that use UITextFieldDelegate in .h file.

in .m file

```
 textfieldname.delegate=self;



 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{


    [textfieldname resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;

}
```

The above code will dismiss keyboard on pressing return key.use below code inside your function  to dismiss the keyboard.

```
[textfieldname resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: He wants to dismiss his keyboard with his method `dismissKeyboard` not when return is tapped.

Comment: -(void) dismissKeyboard
{
   [textfieldname resignFirstResponder]; 
}

Comment: Please see last couple lines of his code, he is already doing that.

Comment: i Guess he might have not connected the delegate to file owner in .xib file.

Comment: He has written that code for `UITapGestureRecognizer`, setting delegate to `UITextField` won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to dismiss your keyboard by pressing anywhere inside your view then there are 2 things you can do:

1:- Have a UIButton which has [UIColor clearColor] and which is equal to the size of the view and in the IBAction of the button you dismiss your keyboard. This is not a good practice though it seems to work.

2:- Go to identity inspector and change your view's class to UIControl class and then add an IBAction to your class that dismisses your keyboard.

I hope this helps.
Cheers!!

Comment: and @lukasz is correct about dismissing the keyboard in that manner.